# React Native ScrollView with single child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, layout

I want to have a fullscreen `ScrollView` which contains all of the contents of my `Home` screen in my app. The issue I'm facing is that **it works as expected when I have two child components for the `ScrollView` (I added a `Text` component just to try it), but not if I just have the single content `View` that I want**.

The contents of `<View style={style.content}>` are taller than the screen size, so it should scroll. But when I remove `<Text style={{margin: 60, marginTop: 800}}>Here is some text</Text>` **the entire screen goes white**.

Here's what I've heard about ScrollView:

- It needs a limited height (but I should have that since all of the content is currently static (no dynamic data) and all of my components there have a fixed height)
- You need to use `{flex: 1}` on the components inside the ScrollView (I have this style set on my `Container` component)

Here is my Home component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Text
} from "react-native";

import { LinearGradient } from "expo";
import MaterialCommunityIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons"
import Color from "color";

import globalStyles from "../config/globalStyles";
import Container from "../components/Container/Container";
import Header from "../components/Header/Header";
import FullWidthImage from "../components/Images/FullWidthImage";
import MainFeedbackText from "../components/Text/MainFeedbackText";
import MainStatistics from "../components/Statistics/MainStatistics";
import Button from "../components/Buttons/Button"

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{borderColor:"red", borderWidth: 2}}>
                <Container>
                    <View style={style.content}>
                        <MainFeedbackText/>
                        <Button
                            text="START NEW WORKOUT"
                            textStyle={{fontSize: 24}}
                            buttonStyle={{
                                backgroundColor: globalStyles.colors.green,
                                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                            }}
                            icon={<MaterialCommunityIcon style={style.settings} name="dumbbell" color="white" size={30}/>}
                        />
                        <Button
                            text="My workouts"
                            textStyle={{fontSize: 24, paddingRight: 40}}
                            buttonStyle={{
                                backgroundColor: Color("black").fade(0.8),
                                paddingHorizontal: 20,
                                margin: 20
                            }}
                            icon={<MaterialCommunityIcon style={style.settings} name="format-list-bulleted" color="white" size={20}/>}
                        />
                        <MainStatistics/>
                    </View>

                    {/**TODO: ScrollView breaks when removing this line*/}
                    <Text style={{margin: 60, marginTop: 800}}>Here is some text</Text>

                    <StatusBar translucent={false}/>
                    <LinearGradient colors={["transparent", globalStyles.colors.dark]} style={style.gradient}>
                        <View style={style.image}>
                            <FullWidthImage requireSource={require("./lifting.jpg")}/>
                        </View>
                    </LinearGradient>
                    <Header/>
                </Container>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        opacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: -1,
    },
    gradient: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        zIndex: -1
    },
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        position: "absolute",
        top: 80,
        height: 4000,
    }
});
```

Comment: You should add ScrollView to that component which needs scrolling so i suppose in your case that'd be the View component inside Container.

Comment: I believe you should set height to child component inside the `ScrollView`, in this case `Container`. try setting a fixed height and check the result.

Comment: @HamzaBaig What do you mean with add a ScrollView to a component, wrap the component in a ScrollView? It is already wrapped in a ScrollView (and then in a Container which has `flex: 1`, so it shouldn't make a difference).

Comment: @Shadow_m2 Setting the height of `Container` to e.g. `4000` and removing the `Text` component just results in a white screen as described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}` for `ScrollView` to become fullscreen.